# Is it not possible to eager load navigation & collection properties when using IDbSet.Find method?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

It seems that this isn't possible, since `.Include` is an extension method that does not return an `IDbSet`. I know that the entity returned is attached to the context, and the properties can be lazily-loaded. But what if I want to encapsulate the ability to return an entity that is detached from the context, and has eagerly-loaded properties?

Is it better to just use `.Where` instead of `.Find`? I believe the difference is that `.Where` will always hit the database, but `.Find` will look in the context heap first. It seems hitting the database once might be acceptable, because I wouldn't have to have n + m additional queries to lazily-load the properties.

Comment: You have answered your own question :)

Comment: @Eranga thank you for the confirmation.